# Incremental page views on asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I want views column incremented by 1 every time user visit the page in the database, i did code as follows but  it just show 1 all the time

```
    var updateCommand = "UPDATE Items SET views=@0 + 1  WHERE id=@1";
    viewsdb.Execute(updateCommand, views, id);
```

Comment: is the correct value being passed to the database? where are you populating the `views` variable?

Comment: value is by default 0 in the database, and everytime user refreshes the page this update command should whatever value in the db plus 1

Comment: but is it doing so? what does sql profiler say is happening?

Comment: it works fine when i run this query in db Update dbo.Items set views = views + 1 where id = 1 but i am wondering if that's not happening in my updatecommand in the original post's code